# Can't easily access and re-render elements from within jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render a partial and rerender elements of my page with updated elements from said partial. My js with erb as of right now looks like this (which I'm not happy with):

```
var showPage = '<%= j render partial: "orders/show-price", locals: {variant: @variant, line_item: @line_item} %>'
$('[data-unit-price]').html($(showPage)[0])
$('[data-total-price]').html($(showPage)[2])
```

`showPage` returns a string of HTML:

```
<p data-unit-price="">Unit Price: 11.86</p>
<p data-total-price="">Total: 118.60</p>
```

And `$(showPage)` returns `T.fn.init(3) [p, text, p]`

Ordinarily, I'd just do something like:

`$('[data-unit-price]').html($('[data-unit-price]', showPage))`

which in fact exists similarly elsewhere in my code:

```
var sidebar = '<%= j render partial: "layouts/sidebar" %>'
if($('[data-cart-link]').length){
  $('[data-cart-link]').html($('[data-cart-link]', sidebar))
} else {
  $('[data-cart-link-prepend-target]').prepend($('[data-cart-link]', sidebar))
}
```

where sidebar also returns an html string. The above example works as desired in that it takes updated information from a rendered partial and rerenders that element in the DOM.

What am I doing wrong here? What is different about the two situations? I want to be able to find my elements by attribute rather than by array index, but I'm not having any luck.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because when you provide a selector a context to search within, as you are in this line: `$('[data-cart-link]', sidebar)`, it uses `find()` internally. This will not work for the HTML you have stored in `showPage` because there is no parent element to `find()` within, hence nothing is returned.

The solution to this problem is to instead use `filter()` to search through all elements in the current collection:

```js
var showPage = `<p data-unit-price="">Unit Price: 11.86</p>
<p data-total-price="">Total: 118.60</p>`;
var $showPage = $(showPage);

$('[data-unit-price]').append($showPage.filter('[data-unit-price]'));
$('[data-total-price]').append($showPage.filter('[data-total-price]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-unit-price></div>
<div data-total-price></div>
```

Also note the use of `append()` here, as you're providing a jQuery object to the method, not a string.

Comment: Ultimately I opted to simply render the whole of showPage inside a parent div, but your answer provided very helpful information. I didn't realise what my syntax was actually doing until now. Thanks.